# Gastby error when installing gatsby-source-strapi

Tags: gatsby, strapi, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-strapi

I am using Gatsby for my front-end and Strapi for my back-end. I have installed Gastby 5.2.0 and I want to install gatsby-source-strapi to communicate with the Strapi API, but when I try to install it I get this [image: error].

I changed the node version, the gatsby version... Would you know where this error comes from? I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request to update Gatsby to the new version 5, but that has not been done yet. You'll have to be patient for a while: https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi/pull/358
Or you can install it with Gatsby 4.

Comment: You can just use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and it'll work.